# Is it possible to elevate privileges of multiple child processes, prompting only once?

Tags: c#, uac, elevated-privileges

all. This may seem like a duplicate question, there being plenty of questions about elevating and de-elevating child processes on here.

I'm aware of the using `UseShellExecute = true` together with the `Verb = "runas"` option to start one's child process with elevated rights.

Example (found in many of the answers):

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
{
    UseShellExecute = true, // !
    Verb = "runas", 
};
```

My problem here is not starting child processes with elevated access, I'd like to know if there is a way to prompt for elevated access only once, after which starting the same child process a few times, say 8 of them for example.

The application I'm working on uses a Queuing system to process tasks. According to the user's number of cores, a child process (QueueProcessor) is started for each of the cores, which then starts processing this queue. So in essence, I would like to check the user's rights, prompt once for elevated rights, and start all 8 Queue Processors.

I can't use the manifest-route to require the entire application to run in Admin-rights, as this is not an option for many of our users. EDIT as per @MPatel's comment: To clarify, we specifically don't force users to run the application as an Administrator as per design decisions.

And obviously you can see how it would become annoying when you'd have to click the UAC dialogue 8 times each time you'd want to run one of these tasks.

I came across this article: [Vista UAC The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide), during my searches, but I'm having trouble implementing the C++ dll in my C#, .NET 3.5 project. This is the article that basically lead me to ask whether this is possible.

One other thing which might be worth mentioning: I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the problem slightly. The users have to have at least enough access to use the basic SQL-funtionality our program uses. So I think my problem might be less about having the child process run with full admin-rights, as just getting the child process to start up. The issue I'm getting is that .NET won't allow certain users to run child processes from the running app. Having the user run the main app using "Run As Administrator" seems to fix this problem. Is there some UAC specific right I can possibly set once through a prompt to simply allow the main App to start the child.exe's?

Comment: Start the parent process with elevated privileges? Surely that would start all children processes with the same permissions.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit. We specifically don't force users to run as administrators. Which why I added the last bit in the question, our users have at least have access to the sql server and to execute queries, so this is really all the rights I need. So I think my issue may be more forcing the parent app to be able to start child processes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write your own process (C# application) that will be started by your main application with elevated rights.

Than, whenever you need to start a process with elevated rights you forward this request to your elevated process by using some kind of inter-process communication (NamedPipes, TcpClient, etc.) and that one will start this process as usual, leading to an elevated process cause it was started from an elevated one.

Comment: +1. The problem here is that elevation happens repeatedly for differnet pricess subtrees. This approach makes sure there is one elevated subtree available waiting for commands.

Comment: +1, Or we may even install a windows service with required privilege and let it spawn children for our task, then there will be no UAC popup at all (except the one during service installation or on manual starting it).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Microsoft released a guideline about handling UAC. The philosophy behind showing annoying user prompts is that Microsoft wants developers to create application with minimal permissions from the scratch. I do NOT think there are some magic parameter to fork several elevated child processes with only one user prompt.

In compare with solution of elevating your main application, you can create a server/service application and move all administrative stuffs into it. The application will run without UI in background. It will show UAC prompt only once. You can setup a thread pool with particular pool size for handling tasks efficiently. When you create any child process, the child process can run non-administrative tasks locally and silently. To do an administrative task, it will communicate with the server/service application using any IPC technique.

I hope my advice can help you. Sure, the solution requires extra coding effort. I can share more leads, if you think the approach is doable for you.